# Error on any command npm. Error on any command npm

Tags: npm

`TypeError: invalid options argument at optsArg (/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/opts-arg.js:13:11) at mkdirp (/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:11:10) at inferOwner.then.owner (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/gentle-fs/lib/mkdir.js:14:5) Error: npm.load() required at Object.get (/usr/share/npm/lib/npm.js:59:13) at process.errorHandler (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:32) at process.emit (events.js:198:13) at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34) /usr/share/npm/lib/npm.js:59 throw new Error(npm.load() required) ^ Error: npm.load() required at Object.get (/usr/share/npm/lib/npm.js:59:13) at process.errorHandler (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:32) at process.emit (events.js:198:13) at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:497:27)`

What's going on here? I do not understand anything

clean ubuntu focal.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling npm? try this: https://sebhastian.com/reinstall-npm/

Answer (score 0):

Deleted /node_modules and installed npm via **nvm**. Now it works.